# clarification Johansen cointegration matlab

Tags: matlab, cointegration

To my understanding the Johansen cointegration test, will test first if the time series have  zero cointegrations, if rejected, the Johansen test will test for one cointegration, if rejected, it will test for two cointegrations of more.. If you cannot reject the null hypthesis for the second time in the row it means the times series has one cointegration.. I use matlab and using the Johansen test I get the following result: see pic.

[image]

I think the results are weird, because you cannot reject the null hypothesis of zero cointegration, but you can reject the null hypothesis of one cointegrations.. Has someone an explanation?

Answer (score 1):

Such a result could mean that your two time series are already independently stationary. In such a case, you would not need to look for a cointegration relationship.

Recall that Johansen's method supposes that you test a group of time series that are integrated of order 1. You might want to check the stationarity of your 2 time series first.